# Can I reuse this duplicate function that reads a property file?

Tags: java, optimization

I created a function that reads a given property file and returns a map with the information. This has been useful as the project has multiple files.
However 1 file in particular needs me to not only return a different type of map, but also requires an extra "if" clause.
This is really messing with me as I feel like there's probably a way to not duplicate all this code

```
/**
 * Loads the given property file and places all it's content in a map
 * @param properties
 * @param fileDirectory
 */
public static Map<String, String> readProperties(Properties properties, String fileDirectory) {
    Map<String, String> propertiesFileContent = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        properties.load(new FileInputStream(fileDirectory));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Useful.printTimeStampedMessage(Constants.EXCEPTION_FILE_NOT_FOUND);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Useful.printTimeStampedMessage(Constants.EXCEPTION_IO);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    
    for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
        propertiesFileContent.put(key, properties.get(key).toString());
    }
    return propertiesFileContent;
}

/**
 * Loads the follow property file and places all it's content in a map
 * @param properties
 * @param fileDirectory
 */
public static Map<String, LocalDateTime> readFollowProperties(Properties properties, String fileDirectory) {
    Map<String, LocalDateTime> propertiesFileContent = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        properties.load(new FileInputStream(fileDirectory));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Useful.printTimeStampedMessage(Constants.EXCEPTION_FILE_NOT_FOUND);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Useful.printTimeStampedMessage(Constants.EXCEPTION_IO);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    
    for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
        if(!properties.get(key).equals("U") && !properties.get(key).equals("FB")) {
            propertiesFileContent.put(key, LocalDateTime.parse((CharSequence) properties.get(key)));
        }
    }
    return propertiesFileContent;
}
```

As you can see, the differences between the 2 functions are very small.

1. The type of Map changes from `Map<String, String>` to `Map<String, LocalDateTime>`
2. The second function has one extra `if` inside the `for`, to exclude certain properties from being read

Comment: Why not use the first procedure to load into a map and then convert that map to a new map?

Comment: cause that would double the complexity from n to 2n (wich is pretty much the same but it will grow twice as fast as the map grows to infinity) @RealSkeptic

Comment: That's not how complexity works. 2n is the same as n. Plus it's not 2. When you read the file, you are I/O bound. Disk operations take a lot longer than in-memory operations. So you could say that your file-reading procedure takes 10N, and with the additional map scan it will be 12N. Negligible.

Comment: 1 operation is not 10N, that's not how it works
not to mentioning you would be spending twice as much memory with 2 maps
I apreciate the input though

Comment: You don't know what I/O bound is? Look it up. Note that I have a B.Sc in Computer Science, and experience of 33 years in programming. And that experience says that you are optimizing where you shouldn't, and that you should put more effort into clean code than into saving 2 seconds of computer time.

Comment: I know what I/O bound is. 1 operation is 1 operation. not 10.
there's no need to bring the Argumentum ad verecundiam into an argument.
Like I said I'm not gonna use that solution but thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

You can write one method and make it accept a boolean as parameter , if the boolean is true the first version will run and return a Map<String,String>, else the second version run and return a Map<String,LocalDateTime>  .

So your method should return a Map<String , ?> :

```
// if you need to return Map<String, LocalDateTime> 
// you should pass true
// if you need to return Map<String,String> you should pass false
Map<String, ?> propsLoad(boolean activeStringStringReturn) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(new FileInputStream("Put your Path here"));
    
    if (activeStringStringReturn== false) {
        Map<String, String> mapProp = prop.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> (String) e.getKey(), e -> (String) e.getValue()));
        return mapProp;
    } 
    else {
        Map<String, LocalDateTime> mapProp = prop.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> !((String) e.getKey()).equals("U") && !((String) e.getKey()).equals("FB"))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> (String) e.getKey(), e -> LocalDateTime.parse((CharSequence) (e.getValue()) )));
        return mapProp;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the filters and collects, i had no idea those exitested. Will use them!!
the boolean not so much. adding a parameter that's 99% of the times false, sounds like more repeated code than the current versions

Comment: actually, on a second note I will keep the for if instead of the filter collect, @Oussama ZAGHDOUD , it's way harder to read with all the casts and the complexity increases with them